# Issue with loop and BufferedReader

Tags: java, while-loop, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I'm getting an strange issue in a loop that is reading a BufferedReader and never ends...

This is the code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

int b;
            StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1 ) {
                buff.append((char) b);
            }
            System.out.println(buff.toString());
```

But never arrives to the last line to print buff.toString().
There's anything wrong in this code?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you reading from? (What is 'in'?)

Comment: This code is receiving a HTTP message from a browser (working with sockets), I just would like to print the content of the GET or POST messages to see the content (headers... you know)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the while condition like this.

```
while ((b = in.read()) > -1 ) {
            buff.append((char) b);
        }
```

Comment: CAn you check the return value of in.ready() when the data is not available.

Comment: Hi, this is what I got printing the content of the variable b and in.ready():  10
true
13
true
10
false

Comment: Binish, I have solved the problem using this code: if (!in.ready()) break;  Thank you very much!!!!  :)

Comment: Good! However please read the API doc for ready(). There may be exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is trying to read until EOF (that is the only reason for an input stream/reader to return -1 for the `read()` method).

The problem is that your HTTP connection (and your socket) might be left open (for a while), also leaving your input stream/reader open. So instead of reaching the end condition for your loop, the `in.read()` call will just block, waiting for input.

If you control the "other side" of the connection, you could close it, to see what happens. But I doubt that would work for the use case in general. Instead, you need to parse the message according to the HTTP protocol (see [HTTP/1.1 RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)).

If you only need to parse the headers, then you could use your `BufferedReader`, and read only full lines, until you find an empty line. This will work, because HTTP uses linefeeds (linefeed being `CRLF` in this case) after each header name/value pair, and end the header part with exactly two linefeeds. Everything after that will be the message body.

PS: This is the easy/happy case. Note that a single connection/socket may be re-used for multiple HTTP requests/responses. You may have handle this as well, depending on your requirements.